# Fastest way to process all of the data in a Postgres table?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, lambda

I have a NodeJS application that needs to stream data from an RDS Postgres, perform some relatively expensive CPU operations on the data, and insert it into another database. The CPU intensive portion I've offloaded into an AWS Lambda, such that the Node application will get a batch of rows and immediately pass them to the Lambda for processing. The bottleneck appears to be the speed in which the data can be received from Postgres.

In order to utilize multiple connections to the DB, I have an algorithm which is effectively leapfrogging on sorted IDs, so that many concurrent connections can be maintained. Ex: 1 connection fetches ids 1-100, second one fetches ids 101-200, etc, and then when the first returns maybe it fetches ids 1001-1100. Is this relatively standard practice? Is there a faster method for pulling the data out for processing?

So long as I am below the database's max_connections, would it be arguably beneficial to add more, possibly as additional concurrent applications streaming data out of it? Both the application and the RDS are currently in the VPC, and the CPU utilization on the RDS gets to about 30%, with memory at 60%.

Comment: {constructing+parsing+executing} query+2*network traffic is a lot of work for only 100 rows.

Comment: Not doing 100 rows, was just giving example to demonstrate the leapfrog mechanism, sorry.

Comment: You appear to be a code-guy, not a data guy. Besides: if the bottleneck is a CPU-intensive thingy, why bither?

Comment: Because after offloading the processing to a lambda, the bottleneck moves from the CPU to the Postgres read.

Answer (score 1):

It would likely be MUCH faster to dump your Postgres database into a CSV file or export it directly to flat files, dump the flat files into S3 after splitting them up, then have workers process each batch of files on their own.

Streaming data out of Postgres (particularly if you're doing it for millions of items) will take a LOT of IO and a very long time.